# I am trying to set a cookie and its path but not able to set the path correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

When I use like 
`var` values = some array which depends on the user selections.

`document.cookie = "filters="+values;`

How can I set the path for this cookie if the path is /abc-def/

Comment: you can only store string in cookie not an array

Comment: Ok Optimus. If it is string..how can i set the path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

values = JSON.stringify(values);
document.cookie = "filters="+values;

Comment: What about the path ?

Comment: document.cookie = "filters="+values+"; path=domain.com;"

Comment: Its not working with Chrome and working on all other browsers

Comment: Can you copy paste your code here. This should work in all the browsers

Comment: Its working in Chrome now, sorry its my mistake in code.But there is problem with IE9. I am using the way as document.cookie = "filter ="+values+"; path=/abc-def;";

Comment: There is a problem with path in IE9 as when i don't use path it is working fine. I am using like this without path as document.cookie = "filter_id="+values;

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.cookie="name=value;path=/";
```

Comment: If i do in this way it is not storing the real value. It is storing as **"filters=value"**. I  need it store as **"filters=10( value dynamically changes)"**

Comment: Try this : var myAry = [1, 2, 3];
$.cookie('name', JSON.stringify(myAry),path:'/');

Answer (score 0):

This will help you more

```
$.cookie("test", 1, {
   expires : 10,           //expires in 10 days

   path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                           //(default: path of page that created the cookie).    
   domain  : 'google.com',  //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie

                   //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

   secure  : true          //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                           //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                           //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
});
```